Flutter Home.dart Sorting Issue: Reports Sorted by Time, but Corresponding Ranges Not Displayed Correctly
In my Flutter app's home.dart file, I'm encountering an issue with sorting reports by time. When I sort the reports by time, the newly added reports reorder correctly, but their corresponding ranges are not displayed accurately. For instance, if there's a report far from the current location by 10 km and another report added later is far by 100 km, the latter should appear at the bottom after sorting by time. However, when I apply the time sorting, the newer report does move to the top, but its corresponding range (100 km) doesn't display; instead, it displays the range (10 km) from the previous report card.
This is when I sort by range which work fine
This is sort by time. The corresponding range of that report card are not displayed correctly
I attempted to sort the reports by time in the home.dart file of my Flutter app. I expected that when I sorted the reports by time, the newest reports would appear at the top, and their corresponding ranges would also display accurately. Specifically, I anticipated that if a newer report had a greater distance from the current location, it would reflect that distance accurately after sorting
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _sortBy = 'Range';
  List<Report> reports = [];
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchReports();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchReports() async {
    final response = await ReportService.getAllReports();
    if (response.success && response.payload != null) {
      setState(() {
        reports = response.payload!.reports
            .map((r) => Report(
                  incidentType: r.type,
                  location: r.user,
                  imageUrl: r.image,
                  userName: r.user,
                  reportDescription: r.description,
                  range: r.latitude, //Will change later, this is from old code
                  reportTime: r.time.toString(),
                  title: r.title,
                  latitude: r.latitude,
                  longitude: r.longitude,
                ))
            .toList();
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      (response.message);
    }
  }

  String _formatTimeAgo(DateTime dateTime) {
    return timeago.format(dateTime);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_sortBy == 'Range') {
      reports.sort((a, b) => a.range.compareTo(b.range));
    } else if (_sortBy == 'Time') {
      reports.sort((a, b) => b.reportTime.compareTo(a.reportTime));
    }

    // Get the screen height
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    // Calculate the height of the white box to cover 70% of the screen vertically
    double whiteBoxHeight = screenHeight * 0.85;

    // Calculate the space left at the top of the page
    double spaceAtTop = screenHeight - whiteBoxHeight;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: const Color(0xFFFF6947),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 20,
              ),
              color: const Color(0xFFFF6947),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(width: 60),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Home',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 35,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            shadows: [
                              Shadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                blurRadius: 5,
                                offset: const Offset(1, 5),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfilePage()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          AssetImage('assets/images/jerrymeme.jpg'),
                      radius: 30,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: spaceAtTop,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xFFEBF4FF),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 7,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: _sortBy,
                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _sortBy = newValue!;
                            });
                          },
                          items: <String>['Range', 'Time'].map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  isLoading
                      ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                      : Expanded(
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemCount: reports.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    DateTime reportDateTime = DateTime.parse(
                                        reports[index].reportTime);
                                    return CustomReportCard(
                                      title: reports[index].title,
                                      type: reports[index].incidentType,
                                      imageUrl: reports[index].imageUrl,
                                      description:
                                          reports[index].reportDescription,
                                      reporterName: reports[index].userName,
                                      location: reports[index].location,
                                      range: reports[index].range,
                                      reportTime:
                                          _formatTimeAgo(reportDateTime),
                                      latitude: reports[index].latitude,
                                      longitude: reports[index].longitude,
                                    );
                                  },
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ReportPage()),
          );
        },
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFB5432A),
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
    );
  }
}


You either sort by range or by time. Instead you could sort by time and range using a combined comparator. This example shows how to sort a list based on several attributes.
